# How can I set landscape mode in Safairi in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

In Android I use `ScreenOrientation: lock()` method from javascript which works well. But this package doesn't support Safari in iOS.

My question is how can force Safari browser to landscape mode?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock

Thanks in advance.

How can force Safari in iOS to landscape mode?